# Lenovo: partially forgot BIOS and Windows pwd

Tags: windows, bios, passwords, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop that I havent used in a while. I set it up to have BIOS password on start up, and I partially forgot the password. I also know there's a Windows password afterwards that I also partially forgot.

I have tried some things that people suggested online but nothing has worked. Anyone has a suggestion? preferably something simple.

Even if you only know a solution for one or the other (BIOS or Windows) it'd help.

Comment: I have tried some things that people suggested online but nothing has worked. Which one?

Comment: For the BIOS, if methods online don't help, the only other solution would be buying the BIOS microchip online _(check eBay, Amazon, etc. as they're usually ~$30 or so)_ and sending the laptop to a company that does PCB soldering with a microscopic soldering station since a microscope will likely be required to ensure it's correctly seated on the PCB soldering pads. For the Windows password, IIRC [Hiren's BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) _([original](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) non-WinPE version)_ has DOS utilities that can change or remove that passphrase, unless it's Bitlocker.

Comment: *Caveat:* It's not hard to remove a *local* Windows password, and then put in a new, if desired, but if logon is through Microsoft, you'd need *their* help to reset the password.